# git move sub project to the root of the reposotory

Tags: eclipse, git, bitbucket, git-branch

I am using GIT repository to check-in my changes. in repository, I have a project and under that I am checking in everything. But while configuring 'OpenShift' in eclipse using jbosstools, it is saying

```
    The project <projectname> is not at the root of your git repository 
and appears to be a sub-project. Please copy your project to it's own repository.
```

How can I move my project to root using eclipse? without using command prompt.

Comment: This looks like a mess and I probably wouldn't touch it without using the command prompt.

Comment: okk then tell me using command prompt.. :(...you are scaring me :(

Comment: Open the Git console, change directories to the root of your project, and type `git status`.  What does it say?

Comment: I have not "touched" eclipse for a long time, but I remember many years ago it stored git repository of a project outside of the project directory. Please,  check root directory and git repo directory.

Answer (score 0):

Though the question is quite old, would like to add the answer so that it helps someone.

I have faced similar issue, Resolved it by using following steps,

1. Click File -> New -> Other -> Git Repository.
2. Browse and select your project you want to deploy.

   NOTE: do not select the folder above your project.
    Example:
    -Workspace
    |-project1
    |-project2

   And you want to deploy project1, do not select Workspace, select prject1
3. Right click on project -> Team -> Add to index
4. Right click on project -> Team -> Commit
5. Now deploy the project on openshift

hope it helps.